# How to test a sample of cigarette tobacco for its nicotine content?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

I was wondering how one would go about testing samples of different cigarette tobaccos for their nicotine content. Is there a kit of some kind available online to do this?

Comment: A cursory search didn't reveal anything along the lines of a "home kit," but check out [this commercial product](http://seal-analytical.com.tempdomain.com/Markets/TobaccoAnalysis/tabid/66/language/en-US/Default.aspx) and accompanying brochure for details pertaining to an industrially-market analysis tool suite.

Comment: You could do a bio-assay. Nicotine is a poison to insects.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, [nicotine analysis](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187853521000211X) is prohibitively complicated and expensive for a home kit. The presence of other alkaloids similar to nicotine pretty much necessitates that somewhat expensive equipment (i.e. a gas chromatograph) is used to first separate out the nicotine prior to analysis (typically by mass spectroscopy).

The only practical means for a layperson to test tobacco products for nicotine content is to out-source the work to a GC-MS equipped laboratory that routinely performs such analysis.